# SQL : Compound Subset Select

Tags: c#, sql, select, join, union

LAYOUT:
I have a Subscriber database with Subscriber info in a table, all with unique AccountID's.

I have multiple History databases with a History table in each, all pertaining to the AccountID's in the Subscriber database.

I NEED:
I need a list of the most recent History record entered, in any of the History databases, for each AccountID in the Subscriber data.  1 record per AccountID.

I can achieve this with multiple hits to the database, but there are potentially millions of records and that doesn't sit well in my head.  I want to make this happen in one hit.

Help.  Me.  Thanks.

Here's something I have tried already, but it doesn't give me a single record per AccountID...

```
SELECT 
MAIN.*, 
ISNULL(SubData.Name, '') AS [Name], 
ISNULL(SubData.AcctLineCode, '') AS AcctLineCode, 
ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(SubData.AcctNum)), '') AS AcctNum 

FROM 
(
    SELECT AccountID, AlarmDate, AlarmCode FROM [History1113]..SignalHistory WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID FROM Subscriber..[Subscriber Data])
    UNION 
    SELECT AccountID, AlarmDate, AlarmCode FROM [History1013]..SignalHistory WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID FROM Subscriber..[Subscriber Data])
    UNION 
    SELECT AccountID, AlarmDate, AlarmCode FROM [History0913]..SignalHistory WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID FROM Subscriber..[Subscriber Data])
) 
AS MAIN 

LEFT JOIN Subscriber..[Subscriber Data] AS SubData ON Main.AccountID = SubData.AccountID 

ORDER BY AccountID, AlarmDate DESC
```

Comment: am I getting this correct.  you have MULTIPLE history tables?

Comment: How many history tables do you have and do those tables have changing names?  There are a couple ways you can do this.

Comment: if you've got history records in separate *databases* , sounds like you're going to end up using some variety of a union

Comment: Are the separate databases at least on the same server?

Comment: Subscriber data is in a single database.  History is broken out into multiple databases, basically by Month/Year.  We get millions of history records per month, so we create a new database each month to cut down on database size.

History databases all have unique names.  Ex. History1113 (for November 2013).
All databases are on same server.

Comment: That sounds like a broken design. Multiple tables of identical structure almost never makes sense.

Comment: Not multiple tables in a single database.  Multiple databases, with same structure.  They older databases rarely get queried, only in this one circumstance where I am creating a report.

Comment: It's really not the best design, but I've seen it used out of nessecity before.  Can your databases talk to each other (linked servers maybe?)

Comment: Single database server.  Multiple databases on the server.

Comment: Whether or not you like the design is irrelevant.  We are required by UL and the government to do certain things the way we do them.  That's all I can say.

Comment: It's not made better by having the tables live in different databases.

Comment: You have two issues then...I'd use a view (the union all you have here works, it's just bulky).  Second issue is you have no aggregate or logic to reduce it down to one row.  Is it max(alarm_date) you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it as a view.  Biggest issue will be making sure the view can see all the history tables if they are in seperate databases.  You may have to get into linked servers

```
Create view historytable
as
select * from historytable1
union all 
select * from historytable2
union all
etc...
```

Now query from historytable as if it was a table with all rows in it.

Edit:
the statement you've added has no aggregates, so it has no method of filtering down (or grouping by) into one record.

To your reply:

Lets call my view above main so I don't have to type so much.

```
Select account_id, max(alarm_date) as maxdate from main group by account_id
```

This simple select brings back to most recent record.  Inner join it so it functions as a filter.

```
select ...
from main
inner join (Select account_id, max(alarm_date) as maxdate from main group by account_id) maxdate
on main.account_id = maxdate.account_ID and maxdate.maxdate = main.alarm_date
```

Add your subscriber join to the bottom of that and fill in the columns you need

Comment: I should point this out...Getting the data from multiple databases has not been an issue.  The last issue I am having is selecting the MOST RECENT entry for each account number, regardless of which database it is in.

So, I have a list of account numbers.  I need to sift through multiple databases, per account number, finding the most recent record entered for that account number.

Comment: Answer editted to include some max() logic for you.  Simple idea, use a query to find the account_id and it's max alarm date then inner join it to your main query to use it as a filter.  You will get multiple rows with this if you have multiple account_id/alarm_dates that are the same (usually not an issue if the date includes a time component)

Comment: See, that's why I come here Twelfth.  I didn't think of attacking it from reverse.  Let me see if I can get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

With a little help from a couple of you, I was able to figure this out.  So, thank you all.

Here's a code snippet of how I got it to work.  I still need to do some joins to bring in account info, but this was the hard part.

`

```
SELECT MAIN.AccountID, MAX(MAIN.AlarmDate) AS AlarmDate FROM
(
SELECT AccountID, MAX(AlarmDate) AS AlarmDate FROM [History1113]..SignalHistory WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID FROM Subscriber..[Subscriber Data])
GROUP BY AccountID

UNION

SELECT AccountID, MAX(AlarmDate) AS AlarmDate FROM [History1013]..SignalHistory WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID FROM Subscriber..[Subscriber Data])
GROUP BY AccountID

UNION

SELECT AccountID, MAX(AlarmDate) AS AlarmDate FROM [History0913]..SignalHistory WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID FROM Subscriber..[Subscriber Data])
GROUP BY AccountID
)
AS MAIN

GROUP BY MAIN.AccountID
```

`

Comment: sorry, added a comment, but turned out I was wrong.  hehe, happy to help